# Query related to SOBO concept of docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I want to send the envelope on behalf of user1. Steps:

1) get taccess token for user1

2) get taccess token for user2 using user1's token

3)  trying to send envelope on behalf of user2:
for that HTTP request url is `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}`

```
http Header: X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><SendOnBehalfOf>user2@xxx.com</SendOnBehalfOf><Username>user1@xxx.com </Username><Password>*****</Password><IntegratorKey>********</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
```

Now here I need account Id and envelopeId that I am getting after following these two steps

1) Getting login to user1 account using (username, Password, Integrator Key)

2) Creating and sending the envelope from user1
(As mentioned in the link https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/request-a-signature-via-email) but this envelpeId is created when we create the envelope and send it from user1,but I don’t want to send the envelope from User1, it should be sent from user2 - that’s what SOBO concept is all about, right?

So my question, how can I get the envelope Id and account id without sending the envelope?

Comment: I think step 2 is extraneous. Per the documentation, you can use the credentials of user1 to create envelopes & perform a set of API functions as if you were using the credentials of user2. However, you never use any of user2 credentials. Can you please re-review: https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#SOBO/Send%20On%20Behalf%20Of%20Functionality%20in%20the%20DocuSign%20REST%20API.htm?Highlight=SOBO and follow-up w/clarifying questions as needed.

Comment: for step 3 you do not specify envelopeID anywhere, it is returned to you. step 3 is a POST to the /envelope endpoint which will result in one being created, and envelopeID returned in the response.

Comment: Thanks Luis for helping me out here,if am getting it right, we need to create a envelope and use this end point , https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{ACCOUNTID}/envelopes. to POST and header as mentioned in link  docusign.com/developer-center/explore/feature/sobo.Just want to know what need to be pass in the body ??

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? It sounds as if you should put SOBO to the side right now and focus on finding samples of creating envelopes using the API.  There are several ways to create an envelope.

Comment: Ok Luis,I kept SOBO aside.I am following the code mention in this link "https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#quickstart" to create/send a envelope and envelope also getting created,but it will be created/sent on behalf of login account, how to send this envelope on behalf of other account.

Comment: You can simply add the <SendOnBehalfOf> node into your header with the userID (or email) of the user you wish to be the sender.

Comment: Thanks Luis and Thanks Rickey, i was making a silly mistake while adding header,finally got solved,I have one more question to ask.After creating the envelope on others behalf. I want to open the recipient view in new  window (To integrate my app with docusign ).I know  we can apply embedding functionality for logged in user,So is there a way to apply  embedding functionality, if we created envelope on others behalf.

Comment: Adding the same header "Authorization" and "X-DocuSign-Act-As-User" did the job for me ...